# A Google Docs that automatically integrates content from lots of other Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I have shared several Google Docs with particular users and each updates his document on a regular basis. I would like to have a Google Docs that pulls all the content from these individual documents. This "comprehensive document" should be current and up-to-date automatically each time I open it.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?